# grep -v do not filter the lines outputs

Tags: linux, grep

I am doing a search on my linux console by `find /export/home01/ -name sql | grep -v 'Permission denied'`

However, it failed to filter out the lines with "Permission denied"

like showing lines of `find: /export/home01/oracle/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/log: Permission denied`.

What's wrong with my command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, it failed to filter out the lines with "Permission denied"

This is expected: you are only filtering `stdout`, but the error messages (usually) go to `stderr`. Try this:

```
find /export/home01/ -name sql 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied'
```

Comment: Or, instead of grepping for the errors, suppress them right away ;)  **find /export/home01/ -name sql 2>/dev/null**

Comment: Thanks @Employed Russian , I didn't aware they are not stdouts